# Populate Data into Columns of Datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am getting a json object response from the server but unable to render the data into columns.
Appreciate your help.

```
JSON OBJECT RESPONSE:
{
"CHD2": {
"POSName": "CHANDIGARH INDU. AREA-I",
"HODB": "QSR_PHASE-I_CHANDIGARH"
},
"D002": {
"POSName": "DEHRADUN-ASTLEY HALL",
"HODB": "QSR_DEHRADUN_ASTLEY"
},
"J002": {
"POSName": "VAISHALI NAGAR",
"HODB": "QSR_VAISHALI_NAGAR"
}
}
```

JQUERY SCRIPT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Initializing tables...');
    var <a href="//legacy.datatables.net/ref#aaData">aaData</a> = [];
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            data : aaData,
            ajax: {
                url:'http://localhost:81/reporting/outletList.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                dataSrc : "",
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert("There is an error with AJAX!");
                },
            "success": function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                aaData.push([
                        data['CHD2'].POSName,
                        data['CHD2'].HODB
                    ]);
                aaData.push([
                    data['D002'].POSName,
                    data['D002'].HODB
                ]);
                data = aaData;
                console.log(data);
            }},
            /*columns: [
                { data: "POSName"},
                { data: "HODB"}
            ],*/
            "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "No records to display"
            }
            })
        });
    </script>



<div class="panel-body">
     <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>POSName</th>
     <th>HODB</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
```

Still it's not working. JSON Object response is there in the developer tool of Chrome but data is not getting populated in the table.

Comment: you are make your code very much complex you can handle it's in easy way .... please write your html also or your DIV or SPAN class name where you want to update your json responce

Comment: It is unclear where you want to display(render) your data. You may want to create new html table markup with javascript (using retrieved data) and append somewhere on the page.

Comment: Hi,I have added the HTML code for rendering of data. Datatable id is  #dataTables-example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
let data = {
    "CHD2": {
      "POSName": "CHANDIGARH INDU. AREA-I",
      "HODB": "QSR_PHASE-I_CHANDIGARH"
    },
    "D002": {
      "POSName": "DEHRADUN-ASTLEY HALL",
      "HODB": "QSR_DEHRADUN_ASTLEY"
    },
    "J002": {
      "POSName": "VAISHALI NAGAR",
      "HODB": "QSR_VAISHALI_NAGAR"
    }
  },
  dataArray = [];

for (let item in data) {
  let row = {
    "Name": item
  };
  for (let element in data[item]) {
    console.log(data[item][element]);
    row[element] = data[item][element];
  }
  dataArray.push(row);
}
console.log(dataArray);
```

Once that's done `rows` should represent your data. Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/nmhsg1z7/3/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your revert. I am getting the dataArray with 3 fields but the table is not getting populated. Its showing 'processing'. Can you please check my html code for any issues.